# does liquibase generate SQL Diff with SQL 92?

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I want to know if the sql generated with liquibase is the SQL 92 ? Because I want to use Liquibase DiffChangelog on multiple dbms is the sql or the xml generated is supported by multiple databases ?

Comment: Even if it did it won't help you because no DBMS fully supports all aspects of the SQL standard. To my knowledge the generated SQL is based on the DBMS you are connected to.

Comment: I am generating diff against model and database. and my model  is related to multiple dbms so i want once i generate the  sql or the xml diff i update any of my dbms . is the xml generic ?

Comment: The SQL-92 standard defines different levels (Entry, Transitional, Intermediate and Full SQL-92). Most dbms products support the lower levels, none the highest level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML generated will generally be database-agnostic, but there are many many cases where different database engines support the same basic feature in different ways. Even for something as 'simple' as id columns, designing a database schema that works in multiple databases can be very difficult. Some databases support sequences, but not all. Some have auto-generated GUID columns, some don't. The list of differences is huge.